# List controllers are not supported for Profile

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, standardsetcontroller

Is there a workaround for "List controllers are not supported for Profile" error in visualforce page?

Am creating a simple visualforce page to display the profiles in a data table with the pagination using standard set controller.

It seems we can't use standard set controller for profiles,task,campaign members etc.,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pretty much use soql OFFSET instead of standard set controller to achieve this as there wouldn't be more than 2000 profiles in reality

Comment: What if there are more than 2000 rows? Is there any workaround other than OFFSET?